# How to keep track of one specific field in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Context:**

I'm building an app on Firebase where users upload photos that others can access.
When uploading, the user has to indicate the country where the photo was taken.
In the gallery, the users can filter the list of photos by country.

**Question:**

I want to list only the countries that exist in the database, not to list all the countries in the world, e. g. if there are no photos are from Canada, I don't want Canada to be in the list of countries.

When a request is made to the database, the data is paginated, so it only comes back by batches of 25 documents. So it seems impossible to create the list of countries based on the response from the database.

Should I make a document in the database to list the possible countries? It would need to be updated every time a photo is uploaded or deleted (does it make sense?)

How should I keep track of the possible countries?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a document called `contriesFeatured` and have a single field which is an array.

Create a Cloud Functions with [onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#oncreate) trigger. Every time a document is added, it checks if the country is in this array, and if not, it adds it.

This is, however, not very performance or cost effective.

The method you'd like to avoid (creating a document with all existing countries) should be more cost effective.

Comment: for cost effectiveness, it's true. I should put all countries But it would be a lot better for the user experience to only see the countries for wich photos are available. I want all the countries to be available, but just a few of them will actually be listed in the database. thanks for your help!!

Comment: If you think it would be a better user experience but with a bit higher cost, then perhaps you could consider the first route I proposed?